# When activating an updated apk in dev console do i need to republish my app?

Tags: java, android, console

So i make some changes, update an application, upload the newest version to the dev console and hit activate does that update my version or do i have to unpublish it then republish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to unpublish it and republish, once you upload the new version and activate it, it will appear in the android market as the new version.